# SQL case another existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 view that has three columns, `Name`, `Employee`, `Customer`. I'm working on casing the `Employee` and `Customer` columns to be set as a 0 or a 1 based off the yes/no column, not an issue.

However, in the name column, there are some records that have set names such as 'Emp' and I want to somehow case that information into the Employee column. When I try to case the `Employee` column using the `Name` column it doesn't seem to parse correctly.

```
CASE 
   WHEN Employee = 'No' 
      THEN '0' 
   WHEN Employee = 'yes' 
      THEN '1' 
   ELSE '0' 
END
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work correctly and could use some guidance.

```
CASE 
   WHEN table.Name = 'Emp' 
      THEN table.Employee = '1' 
   ELSE '' 
END
```

I have seen several examples with a `as Table Name` in the code but I want to use an existing table with data already in it.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: SQL Server 2008, SQL View.

Comment: Do you want to view the results or update the columns based on the logic?

Comment: Can you give us the fully query, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to combine them into one statement like this?  I'm not sure what you are looking for.

```
CASE 
   WHEN Employee = 'No' 
      THEN '0' 
   WHEN Employee = 'yes' OR table.Name = 'Emp'
      THEN '1' 
   ELSE 0 
END
```

Comment: Yes the OR statement works, thats the ticket, haha. Thank you for the help.